# Extracted HP's .exe BIOS file for microcode update but can't manage to repack it back

Tags: bios

I want to update microcode so i have to extract BIOS.EXE file to make changes
now I want to repack it as it was before, is that eve possible to make it functional BIOS file again?

The update method of delidded.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Figured it out it doesn't need repack of .exe file.  and i did that mod which worked. HAPPY 771 Xeon CPUs work only on some motherboards/chipsets First you just need to verify it it works on your system Then you must! update BIOS microcode files to add support for Xeon CPUs That's it... I confirm this mod works on my motherboard ! > IPIBL-LB